# Conflicting information about bounty expiration date

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, bounty

I've offered a bounty to [my question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/161819/writing-dates-in-texts) and I got a message telling *my bounty has completed and I should award it in the next 24 hours*, but when I back to the given question, it says *the bounty is about to expire in 43 minutes*, as you can see in the image below.

[image: Screenshot]

It looks like a bug.

Comment: This is actually by design according to a similar MSE question; https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235330/bug-in-time-of-expiring-bounty

Comment: @Catija Perfect, I didn't noticed that. Thank you for check it. It looks like a canonical answer for me. Can you please post it all as an answer, so I'll be able to close the thread?

Comment: Yep. I'll do it later tonight. I don't have time right this second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Catija pointed out in a comment, this is by design.  This was confirmed on the network-wide meta in [a pair of comments left by a Stack Exchange employee](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235330/bug-in-time-of-expiring-bounty#comment775086_235330):

> This is by design due to caching and timing. Occasionally you'll see this notification but your bounty will appear to have some time left.
>
> The short version is that the topbar notifications / toasts are run on a scheduled interval, which will sometimes be just ahead of and sometimes just behind the actual bounty expiration

As other users on the same Q&A point out, this is counterintuitive and arguably incorrect behavior even if it's by design, but it doesn't sound like it'll be changing any time soon.